# Image displaying in categories page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

A single WordPress post is displaying an image in the Home page. When I open the Post, the image is not present in the post. So why is that image displaying in the Home page and not available in the post? How do I delete it?

Comment: it might be a featured image, not in content.

Comment: You can delete it from post featured image.